# unable to build the solution after migrating wix 3.11 to wix 4 by using heatwave visual studio extention

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, wix3.11, wix4

In my application everything was working in wix 3.11 ,but due to make it crossplatform we have migrated the some application to .net 6 after that setup also works fine , we can not give a check in setup whether client machine has .net 6 installed or not so we port our wix into wix v4 by using heatwave visual studio extension, but after that during wix build i am getting this below error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4062 The "ReadTracking" task could not be loaded from the assembly 
D:\myDevApp\Applications\_Common\packages\WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork.3.11.2\tools\wix\WixTasks.dll.
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available,
and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  Merge.Process
C:\Users\mySystem\.nuget\packages\wixtoolset.sdk\4.0.1\tools\wix.targets    725
```